# HTTP Session Management in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, nsurlsession

I have to update user location when the user is logged in only. As I need to update location in background mode (I used https://github.com/voyage11/Location repository to receive background mode delegate call), so I put update location call in AppDelegate.

When a user logs into the server and requests any other rest API, HTTP request gets session object. But only update location rest API request doesn't get the session object.

I have tried to send cookie by setting a cookie to the HTTPHeader of request object directly. But, it doesn't contain session object.

```
extension AppDelegate : LocationTrackerDelegate {

func updateLocation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let loc = [ "lat": location.latitude, "lng": location.longitude]


    let urlStr = IRAPIPathManager.sharedManager.pathForUpdateLocation()
    let cookie = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies?.last

    // create post request
    let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = true

    // Set Cookie
    if cookie != nil {
        let date = Utility.getDateStringFromNSDate((cookie?.expiresDate)!, format: "EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ")
        let cooki = "\(cookie!.name)=\(cookie!.value); Path=\(cookie!.path); Expires=\(date); HttpOnly"
        request.setValue( cooki , forHTTPHeaderField: "Set-Cookie")
    }

    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(loc, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in


    }
    task.resume()

}
}
```

When a user logs in to the server, the server sends a session object to the device. When any HTTP rest calls are made, the session object is inserted into the request internally. But, updateLocation API call is only one which does get the session object. Is there any scope of HTTP session object? Please pardon me if I am wrong.

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Show us the code that sets up your NSURLSession, creates a session task, and submits that task. Also show us how you handle being launched if a session task completes when your app is not running.

Comment: Hi Duncan C, I am very sorry for not mentioning details description. Could you please check it again, I edited it now? Please let me if you need any more insight.